# Where are Apache logs when installed in a Snap?

Tags: server, apache2, routing, nextcloud

**ENVIRONMENT**
Completely fresh Ubuntu Server installation, and NextCloud installed via snap.

**PROBLEM**
Browser requests to public IP over WAN time out when routed to Nextcloud server.
Meanwhile, browser requests to that machine's local IP over LAN resolve to web UI as expected.

**WHAT I’VE TRIED**
I’ve confirmed that my port forwarding configs in our router are working.

After getting the timeouts directly following my initial setup, what I did to test was change the rule in our router to point to another IP on our LAN, and spooled up Apache on that machine. After doing so, visiting our Public IP successfully returned the Apache2 Default Page  (sent test requests, both, directly and through KProxy.com).

Next, I reverted the router rule to once again point to the IP for the Nextcloud server, and requests began timing out again.

**HELP NEEDED**
My guess is that the next thing to check would be the Apache logs, but since is was all installed as part of the snap, can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Then after that, maybe I should check the Nextcloud logs... but that doesn't seem too helpful at this stage.  I did find the `/snap/nextcloud/current/logs` directory, but that is currently empty.

1) am I correct to think that the Apache logs are my best next step?
2) if so, where should those be?
3) otherwise, what else should I be looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping relevant answers have been found elsewhere in the meanwhile.

Just for further reference, here is a link to the official documentation related to log management with Nextcloud set up through Snap:
[Managing Nextcloud snap logs](https://github.com/nextcloud-snap/nextcloud-snap/wiki/Managing-logs)

Regarding Apache2, two log files may be found at the following locations:

```
/var/snap/nextcloud/current/logs/apache_access.log
/var/snap/nextcloud/current/logs/apache_errors.log
```